# Removing an item from a generic Dictionary?

Tags: c#, refactoring, templating

I have this:

```
public static void Remove<T>(string controlID) where T: new()
{
    Logger.InfoFormat("Removing control {0}", controlID);
    T states = RadControlStates.GetStates<T>();

    //Not correct.
    (states as SerializableDictionary<string, object>).Remove(controlID);
    RadControlStates.SetStates<T>(states);
}
```

states will always be a SerializableDictionary with string keys. The values' type vary. Is there a way to express this? Casting to `SerializableDictioanry<string, object>` always yields null.

Comment: How is `RadControlStates.GetStates` defined?  If the `as` operator is returning `null`, it's not what you think it is.

Comment: Agreed. Just thought that I would be able to cast all my types to 'object', but that was foolish of me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the non-generic dictionary interface for this:

```
(states as IDictionary).Remove(controlID);
```

Comment: I get the following error: "Error Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey,TValue>' requires 2 type arguments"

Comment: Either add `using System.Collections;` or explicitly say `System.Collections.IDictionary`.

Comment: Do you have any information on why this is the case? I'd like to avoid a similar issue in the future, but I had no idea.

Comment: The generic dictionary interface `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` doesn't support covariance (it doesn't make sense) so you need to either use generics to get `TValue` or fall back to the non-generic interface.

Answer (score 2):

One option is making the type of the value your generic parameter:

```
public static void Remove<TValue>(string controlID)
{
    Logger.InfoFormat("Removing control {0}", controlID);
    SerializableDictionary<string,TValue> states =
        RadControlStates.GetStates<SerializableDictionary<string,TValue>>();
    states.Remove(controlID);
    RadControlStates.SetStates<SerializableDictionary<string,TValue>>(states);
}
```

Comment: T is already being used in GetStates to fetch the proper SerializableDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to pass a lambda down in the method which represents the remove operation.  For example

```
public static void Remove<T>(
  string controlID,
  Action<T, string> remove) where T: new()
{
    Logger.InfoFormat("Removing control {0}", controlID);
    T states = RadControlStates.GetStates<T>();
    remove(states, controlID);
    RadControlStates.SetStates<T>(states);
}
```

And then at the call site pass in the appropriate lambda

```
Remove<SerializableDictionary<string, TheOtherType>>(
  theId, 
  (dictionary, id) => dictionary.Remove(id));
```

Comment: Let me look into this. I don't understand the code entirely, but I am down to learn if this is a viable solution!